# Devise creating funky edit user password path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following all of the instructions for how to allow users to change their password without having a registration form in solution 2 here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

I updated my edit form accordingly as well to reflect the new `user_registration_path`

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
```

The path shows up in rake routes. What I don't get is when the form is rendered, it gets rendered like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users.user" class="edit_user" id="edit_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="D3ZBYyAfI+sXMsJiKy5+ZsjcISg8yqKTDAdXQm6Heqs=" /></div>
```

What is it with this action `/users.user`? This is breaking me when I hit 'update' on the edit form and I'm not sure where it's generating this action from. My routes.rb has this:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]                                          
    as :user do
      get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'    
      put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'            
    end
```

The ultimate error I get is the following:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::RegistrationsController#update
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't appear that your `user_registration_path` takes any parameters. Since you're giving it one anyway, it's interpreted as a format (like RSS or XML). This results in the `UnknownFormat` error since your update action doesn't handle the nonexistent `"user"` format.

The solution: Just remove the `resource_name` parameter from the `user_registration_path` call.